# Subclass of QEditLine with a new SIGNAL

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-signals

I am trying to subclass QEditLine so that I can define a new SIGNAL that sends an object identifier. At the moment, I connect a parent signal to a slot in the new class and from that slot I emits a proper new signal with the additional object identifier.
I cannot understand one thing. The problem is I don't know how to define a new signal function itself. I don't know what I should put there. I mean I know its arguments but I don't know what it shpould do as a function. I am doing this for the first time and it may looks very silly ;p but I really stuck there >.<.
Can anybody please provide some clues. It is probably a very easy problem.

Thanks

```
// myqeditline.h
#ifndef MYQEDITLINE_H
#define MYQEDITLINE_H
#include <QWidget>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QString>
class MyQEditLine : public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyQEditLine(const QString& n, QWidget *parent = 0);
protected:
    QString name;
signals:
    void textChanged(QString textCHanged, QString sender);
protected slots:
public slots:
    void myTextChanged(QString textChanged);
};
#endif // MYQEDITLINE_H

// myqeditline.cpp
#include "myqeditline.h"
MyQEditLine::MyQEditLine(const QString &n, QWidget *parent)
    : QLineEdit(parent),name(n) {
    connect(this,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(myTextChanged(QString)));
}
void MyQEditLine::myTextChanged(QString textChanged) {
    emit textChanged(QString textChanged, QString name);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "to define a new signal function itself"? Did you try `emit textChanged(textChanged, name);`

Comment: Hi. By defining, I mean providing an implementation, a body of function between { and }, like I did with the SLOT and constructor. Does SIGNAL needs to be implemented in myqeditline.cpp?

Comment: I think I have got it. "Signals are automatically generated by the moc and must not be implemented in the .cpp file. They can never have return types (i.e. use void).". http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/signalsandslots.html

Comment: Quick question: why are you creating new implementation of mechanism that already exists in Qt? You can set name to QObject with `setObjectName` and you can in receiver slot use `sender()` method that will give you QObject that sent this signal.

Answer (score 1):

I just realised that the answer to my question is on this [Qt Project](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/signalsandslots.html) website, in section regarding "Signals", in 4th paragraph. It says: "*Signals are automatically generated by the **moc** and must not be implemented in the .cpp file. They can never have return types (i.e. use **void**).*"